# Is it faster to retrieve or filter data from views using stored procedure than getting or filtering data from tables using stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

Are there performance issues when retrieving and filtering data from views than from tables by using a stored procedure?

**Simplification: Is it faster to retrieve or filter data from views using stored procedure than getting or filtering data from tables using stored procedure?**

Comment: This question is a bit muddy in intent: do you mean "views cost more than tables" or that "stored procedures cost more than either"?

Comment: i just simplified and edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

Answer (score 3):

The performance of a view depends on the performance characteristics of the select statement that defines it. You could improve performance over just the select itself by [indexing the view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx)